# Bluetooth Beginner, Need Advice

Tags: bluetooth

So I'm hopelessly lost  right now. I found an attractive bluetooth chip from Nordic Semiconductor (the NRF52840) that I want to use for a couple project ideas I have. Now I have an HC-05 module for my arduino, so I'm not entirely lost on programming a bluetooth module perse, but I really need advice on how I can make my own. I want to make a bluetooth module that works exactly like the HC-05 but on a much smaller scale. I'm talking fitbit small. I'm not making a smartwatch or fitbit, but that's relatively the size I would need it to be.

So bottom line to whoever got lost in that mumbling explanation of my hopelessness, I need some advice on how to develop my own Bluetooth module PCB. The onboard chip will be the aforementioned NRF52480. Thank you to anybody who helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are endeavoring in a very complex task, I would recommend you to start from the reference designs provided by the chip manufacturer. They are very valuable, especially when dealing with RF.

See [here](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.nrf52840.ps/ref_circuitry.html?cp=2_0_0_55#concept_aqp_fd1_fq) and [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/59024/1/90490672/116086), for example. About RF design, this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnRn3Kn_aXg&t=2481s) may be interesting for you as well.